# Moving keyboard when editing multiple textfields with constraints swift

Tags: swift, uitextfield, constraints, uiresponder

I have `UIViewController` which looks like this:

[image]

I set all the relevant `constraints`.

I'm trying to shift the `UIView` up when the keyboard shows up - when I click on the `UITextfields` below.

I have the following code:

```
static func addRemoveKeyboardObserver(addObserver: Bool, keyboardMargin: CGFloat, view: UIView?)
{
    Utils.keyboardMargin = keyboardMargin
    Utils.heightChangingView = view

    if addObserver
    {
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(Utils.keyboardWillChange(notification:)), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(Utils.keyboardWillChange(notification:)), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(Utils.keyboardWillChange(notification:)), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillChangeFrameNotification, object: nil)
    }
    else
    {
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: UIResponder.keyboardWillChangeFrameNotification, object: nil)

        Utils.keyboardHeight = 0
    }
}

@objc static func keyboardWillChange(notification: Notification)
{
    let userInfo = notification.userInfo!
    let beginFrameValue = (userInfo[UIResponder.keyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)!
    let beginFrame = beginFrameValue.cgRectValue

    let viewShouldMove = notification.name == UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification || notification.name == UIResponder.keyboardWillChangeFrameNotification 

    if Utils.keyboardHeight == 0 { Utils.keyboardHeight = -beginFrame.height + Utils.keyboardMargin }

    let duration:TimeInterval = (userInfo[UIResponder.keyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as? NSNumber)?.doubleValue ?? 0
    let animationCurveRawNSN = userInfo[UIResponder.keyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] as? NSNumber
    let animationCurveRaw = animationCurveRawNSN?.uintValue ?? UIView.AnimationOptions.curveEaseInOut.rawValue
    let animationCurve:UIView.AnimationOptions = UIView.AnimationOptions(rawValue: animationCurveRaw)

    if let view = Utils.heightChangingView
    {
        view.frame.origin.y = viewShouldMove ? Utils.keyboardHeight : 0
        UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, delay: TimeInterval(0), options: animationCurve,                                               animations: { view.layoutIfNeeded() }, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

The issue I'm facing is -

[image: when I click the first <code>UITextField</code>, the <code>UIView</code> shifts nicely:]

But then, when I click the second one, it shifts again, and now it looks like this:

[image]

I noticed that if I remove the constraints, the issue goes away, however, I do need to use the constraints.

So, what am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use scrollview for your uiview controller and then you can use notification for adjusting your uiview constraint.

Your UIViewController hierarchy should be like this

ContainerView --> ScrollView --> Content View  --> Now Your View.

I'm suggesting you to use pod 'TPKeyboardAvoiding'  for future animations in scrollview since for every controller you don't want to put notifications to shifting your UIView.

Here is link demo for your UIView shifting https://github.com/Vasu05/ScrollViewExample

Comment: what are the constraints for `ScrollView --> Content View --> Now Your View.`

Comment: how to give constraints for scrollview, contentview

Comment: i am getting red border line

Comment: set scrollview inside container, attach scrollview end to end to container and set its width to containerview . now add contentview attach top ,left , right constraint to scrollview and set content view widht equal to scrollview. Now you have to give height to content view and attach bottom to scrollview end . Hope this helps!