# How to make scrollview up to keyboard height according to iPhone sizes in swift

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard, uitextfield, scrollviewer

I have added `scrollView` top,left,right,bottom 0. in `scrollView` i have added `viewinScrollview` with height 550, in this view i have added `fieldsContainerView`. like below

[storyboard view hierarchy img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CWPos.png)

if i run project in iPhone8 then design looks good, but if i run in iPhone 11 pro i am seeing unnecessary `scrollview`. i have given `scrollview` color is green and `viewinScrollview` color is white.

in iPhone 11 pro i am getting like below, the green space is scroll view i dont want that space after keyboard [iPhone 11 pro](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uWYti.png)

this is iPhone8 simulator [iPhone8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SK1mY.png) i need like this in all iPhone sizes.

here is the code:

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()

      NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardDidShow), name: UIResponder.keyboardDidShowNotification, object: nil)
      NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardDidHide), name: UIResponder.keyboardDidHideNotification, object: nil)

  }

  @objc func keyboardDidShow(notification: NSNotification) {
      let info = notification.userInfo
      let keyBoardSize = info![UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! CGRect
      scrolView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0.0, left: 0.0, bottom: keyBoardSize.height, right: 0.0)
      scrolView.scrollIndicatorInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0.0, left: 0.0, bottom: keyBoardSize.height, right: 0.0)
  }

  @objc func keyboardDidHide(notification: NSNotification) {
      scrolView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets.zero
      scrolView.scrollIndicatorInsets = UIEdgeInsets.zero
  }
```

please help me to remove green color space in all iPhone sizes.

Comment: Try subtracting `view.safeAreaInsets.bottom` from keyBoardSize.height.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove background colour of scrollview in your storyboard .

You can follow my approach for more clarifications .

[moving-keyboard-when-editing-multiple-textfields-with-constraints-swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59300554/moving-keyboard-when-editing-multiple-textfields-with-constraints-swift/59302647#59302647)

Comment: Okay, like this only i want, but in third textfield why its moving up again, there no need to move in iphoneXR right

Comment: bro you didn't answer my comment?? i have added pod 'TPKeyboardAvoiding'
 in my project but it is not working? why? whats wrong?, why u did not import  TPKeyboardAvoiding

Comment: Hi @iPhoneDev you did not need to import 'TPKeyboardAvoiding'  . In your storyboard , set scrollview class name to 'TPKeyboardAvoidingScrollview' in UIViewcontroller . it will work . Use this link for more details https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1126726/how-can-i-make-a-uitextfield-move-up-when-the-keyboard-is-present-on-starting/59317509#59317509

Comment: it works i have accepted ur answer, but in your project keyboard u have next for all textfields in last textfield u r getting done.. how ?? i am getting only return button

Comment: In the inspector tab of each textfields , leave return key to default .  That's what I've done in my project .

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Library which helps you to manage the Textfields inside the scrollView, TableView, CollectionView. You can use this library. With the help of this library you don't need to manage the scrollview content inset for every device.

Github Link:- https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager

Comment: can't we scroll only keyboard height in all iphone sizes, with out adding libraries.. please suggest me

Comment: Then you have to manage things manually for all the iPhones which is too complex.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following Library which helps to manage the textField or textView inside any contentView

Github Link:- https://github.com/Sunilkumar01091985/KeyBoard/tree/master